# Retrieving line items from Braintree Transactions

Tags: node.js, transactions, braintree

The Braintree Transaction API [has a field for lineItems](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/transaction/sale/node#line_items), but how do I use it? The [Transaction response](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/response/transaction/node) doesn't return line items, and there are no lineitems int the control panel for transactions either.

It looks like the line items aren't actually stored anywhere. Am I right? If so, what's the point of them?

I want to show customers an itemised receipt of the transaction (which is a really obvious use case, right?). Is there anyway to get Braintree to generate this as part of the transaction?

I'm using version 2.5 of the Braintree Node.js SDK.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED ANSWER**

[As of version 2.6.0 of the Braintree Node SDK](https://github.com/braintree/braintree_node/blob/26656b81f6c3776900e1084fc707a60606b11595/CHANGELOG.md#260), `lineItems` is an attribute of the `Transaction` response object. See Braintree's associated documentation [here](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/response/transaction/node#line_items).

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

You may use `gateway.transactionLineItem.findAll(someTransactionId, function(err, response) {})` to retrieve the line items associated with a transaction. This is [documented in the tests of the SDK](https://github.com/braintree/braintree_node/blob/29fd26ec36f87f3c7540a44ca3f2d1d7efc317ea/spec/integration/braintree/transaction_gateway_spec.js#L392-L402):

```
specHelper.defaultGateway.transactionLineItem.findAll(response.transaction.id, function (err, response) {
    assert.equal(response.length, 1);
    let lineItem = response[0];

    assert.equal(lineItem.quantity, '1.0232');
    assert.equal(lineItem.name, 'Name #1');
    assert.equal(lineItem.kind, 'debit');
    assert.equal(lineItem.unitAmount, '45.1232');
    assert.equal(lineItem.totalAmount, '45.15');
    done();
});
```

We are in the process of updating our [developer docs](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/) and [Control Panel](https://www.braintreegateway.com/login) to reflect this behavior.

Comment: what would the object look like to declare your line items in the transaction?

Comment: @Tank12 based on the [dev docs](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/transaction/sale/node#line_items) `lineItems` is an array of objects you can include in `transaction.sale()`.

Comment: @Shea I have to say, Braintree's documentation has really left something to be desired. There's no example of how to use lineItems or anything, atleast at this time of writing. Shouldn't have to look at the tests in the SDK to figure that out. I don't mean to be a dick but it's been frustrating for our team.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this was the case a month ago when you asked the question, but it seems that the transaction response does return line items:

https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/response/transaction/node#line_items